importing DATETIME with "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM" into SQL Lite
I have a CSV file with a table:
id        Name              hired_on
-----------------------------------------------------
1        joe               05/25/2021 09:55:42 AM
2        charles           01/21/2019 12:35:12 PM
....

The columns are separated by  "|"
The question I have is how can I import this csv file into SQL Lite that uses the
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

format? Do I need to do some "preprocessing" or is there an SQL Lite cmd that can automatically solve this problem?
